# How to keep direct link for installation PWA

Tags: web-applications, progressive-web-apps, progressive

Hi i've a website with all file for make PWA version.
I need to keep the direct url/link for intallation on mobile ( android or ios ) without access to the website in browser.

For example, i want to send the  direct link in a newsletter for download the PWA.

Thanks in advice

Comment: The install happens using the browser. So I don't believe that is an option for a regular PWA.

Comment: if i want to skip this step? i don't know with QrCode?

Comment: any link to your site installs the service worker and of course performs any caching logic, etc.
The user has to add to their home screen/install your PWA.
The web manifest designates the start URL when the PWA is opened from the home screen icon - start_url property

Comment: There is no skip for the install. It happens in the browser. The user needs to explicitly click on the yes to install (add to home screen) your PWA.